# Switch Case in SQL Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I want to use some `CASE WHEN` statements inside a `WHERE` clause to allow for different `WHERE` criteria depending on a specific variable. I have an idea of how it looks like, but I just don't know if it's possible or what syntax to use.

I would like it to be used as such:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
CASE WHEN @var = 1 THEN ID = 5 END,
CASE WHEN @var = 2 THEN Name = 'Bob' END,
CASE WHEN @var = 3 THEN Color = 'Green'
```

Where for each instance of `@var` the `WHERE` condition is different. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a `CASE` for that:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
(@var = 1 AND ID = 5) OR
(@var = 2 AND Name = 'Bob') OR
(@var = 3 AND Color = 'Green')
```